# Redirecting into another page in Django

Tags: html, django

I am working in a project in Django where someone tries to fill the info of some patients and after hitting the submit button i would like o redirect it into a page with the list of all the existing patients, i am trying using a action tag in the html but it seems not to work, i would like to know what i am doing wrong.

## html

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%load staticfiles%}
{%block body_block%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'patients/css/patientform.css'%}">
    <form action="{% url 'patients'%}"  method="POST">
        <div class="wrapper">
        {%csrf_token%}
        <div class="Patient">
            <h3>Informacion del Paciente</h3>
            {{patientinfo.as_p}}
        </div>
        <div class="Medical">
            <h3>Informacion Medica</h3>
            {{medicalinfo.as_p}}
        </div>
        <div class="Insurance">
            <h3>Informacion de Seguro</h3>
            {{insuranceinfo.as_p}}
        </div>

        <div class="FirstRelative">
            <h3>Antecedentes Familiares</h3>
            <h5>Primer Caso</h5>
            {{first_relative.as_p}}
            <h5>Segundo Caso</h5>
            {{second_relative.as_p}}
        </div>
        </div>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Agregar">
    </form>
{%endblock%}
```

## Url patterns

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('',PatientsList.as_view(),name='patients'),
    path('addpatient',PatientFormView,name='addpatient'),
]
```

Comment: redirect after `Post request` retrieval should be in **views.py**. Learn about it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution to my problem!

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirection should be made after **Post request** retrieval in your **views.py**

```
    # AT POST REQUEST END   
    return redirect("patients")
```

Django Docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Answer (score 0):

In the end of your `PatientFormView` you should redirect with use of:

```py
   return redirect("patients")
```

For more details check Django documentation: [docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)